# Satterthwaite degrees of freedom in cross-classified linear mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

My colleagues and I are running a few experiments using multiple stimuli and participants, where participants were asked to rate a series of targets that varied in perceived strength (strong, weak) on their humor style. There were 8 total targets, 4 'strong' and 4 'weak', with people rating them on how likely each would be to use 4 different humor types. We analyzed this using a linear mixed effects model with random intercepts of participants and stimuli, as shown below:

`fit1 <- lmer(perception ~ strength * humorStyle + (1|id) + (1|stimID), data = dfLF)`

The degrees of freedom for this model came out to be DFn = 1, DFd = 6, despite us having 8 stimuli and 85 participants. What's weird is that when we drop the random intercept of (1|stimID), the DFd increases to 2628 (adding a random slope of 'strength' to the participant intercept changes DFd to 84). I get that cross-classified models account for more variance thus making it a stricter test, but I'm not quite clear on why the change in error DF is so extreme with the multiple random intercepts. Can anybody provide an explanation for this?